# ko.observableArray for multiple values set

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am use knockout ovservable array to store select option data:

example:

```
var anotherObservableArray = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "Bungle", type: "Bear" },
    { name: "George", type: "Hippo" },
    { name: "Zippy", type: "Unknown" }
]);
```

but I want like to set it like this whereby data is pass an array:

```
anotherObservableArray = ko.observableArray([]);


 somefunction({ function(data) {

    anotherObservableArray(data);

    });

 });
```

what does the data have to contain and how do I go about by setting it to name and type?

data consist of array list?

or perhaps I could do like

```
 anotherObservableAray().push(name: data[i], type: 'bear');
 anotherObservableAray().push(name: data[i], type: 'Grumpjaw');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard `push` and `unshift` methods to add items to on observable array. If you want to add multiple items at once, just iterate over them:

```
var observableArr = ko.observableArray();

function addToObservable(arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(item) {
        observableArr.push(item);
    });
}
```